# JQuery: Changing Content to Contact form on clicking button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery to change the contents of a div and replace it with a contact form once a button has been clicked - Hwoever, I can't get this to work at all. Am I on the right lines? Or maybe there is a better way of doing this?

Thank you in advance.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div id="quote">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, no inani everti tincidunt mea, dicam discere mandamus te mea. Odio enim nam te, id oportere facilisis qui. Phaedrum perpetua an his, mea ea facete vivendum. Cu dolor nusquam percipit his.Idque augue temporibus vix an, at cum mandamus democritum. Autem persequeris qui cu. Duo cu menandri eloquentiam efficiantur, vel suavitate corrumpit te. Nam te habemus scripserit, in has oratio minimum interpretaris. Nibh illud id mea, cu meliore alienum vituperatoribus est. Meis fabellas constituto cu vel, paulo omnes fierent ad sea. Nihil graecis epicuri mel ut, elaboraret percipitur ex sit. Sit nullam iudicabit eu. Ut sumo luptatum vim, cu pri aperiam volumus. Ut nam ornatus assueverit, vidisse dolorem habemus id pro. Pro putent indoctum erroribus cu, per an suscipit salutatus complectitur. At oblique euismod molestiae ius. Oratio referrentur at nam. Quod amet viderer ne ius, illud interesset eu sea, pri harum sonet ex. In propriae accusamus duo, per ignota maiestatis te. Duo ut vidit ipsum imperdiet, ea aliquid deseruisse vis. Pri quodsi appareat assueverit ea. Vis ad possim quaeque, sit quodsi impetus detraxit ut. Id est mucius propriae, ius eu integre graecis facilisi. Putant ornatus mei cu, habeo aliquando in pro, per diam mutat platonem in. Ne sea diceret abhorreant, option salutatus repudiandae an pri, ex ius nisl suavitate intellegebat.</p>

        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-9">
          <a href="#quote" class="btn btn-block btn-large btn-success">Get Quote</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img src="img/image.png">
    </div>

  </div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready( function(){
      $("#quote").click( function(){

        $("#quote").html("

        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1>Contact Us</h1>

        <form class="form-horizontal">

        <div class="form-group">
        <label name="Name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name">
        </div>
        </div>  

        <div class="form-group">
        <label name="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email">
        </div>
        </div>  

        <div class="form-group">
        <label name="message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your message"></textarea>
        </div>
        </div>  

          <!-- Checkboxes -->
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="website" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Favourite Search Engine</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">

        <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="option1">YouTube</label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="option2">Google</label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="option3">Yahoo</label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="option4">Baidu</label>
        </div>
        </div>  

          <!-- Radio Buttons-->
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="gender" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Gender</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="genderRadio" value="option1">Male</label>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="genderRadio" value="option2">Female</label>
        </div>
        </div>  

          <!-- Drop Down Menu-->
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="urgency" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Gender</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <select class="form-control">
        <option>Urgent</option>
        <option>Medium</option>
        <option>Low</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        </div>  

          <!-- Submit Button -->
        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-6">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Clear</button>
        </div>
        </div>  



        </form>

        </div>
        </div>

        "});
      });
  </script>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code, but they all stem from the fact that you've embedded a large chunk of HTML within your JS.

Try to **keep HTML and JS totally separated**. A single line of HTML within your JS isn't always terrible, but for such a long block of HTML definitely don't embed it within the JS like you've done there:

1. it's easy to introduce bugs and syntax errors (which you have done there, things like unescaped double quotes)
2. it's difficult to maintain
3. it looks messy

---

Instead, put both of the `<div>`s in your HTML from the beginning.

Obviously, you don't want that second `<div>` to be visible when the page first loads, so hide it using CSS (`display: none;`). This way, it won't be visible to the user at all when the page loads.

Then, in your JS when the button is clicked, simply use `$("#myFirstDiv").hide()` to hide the first `<div>`, and `$("#mySecondDiv").show()` to show the contact form `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

That's a quote problem...

```
$("#quote").html("

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">...");
```

Will put `<div class=` in the element...

Escape the double quotes inside your html or switch to single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

For better readability and maintainability you should put the html in separate file and load either file or part of the file by using the below.

```
$("#quote").load("HtmlPageUrl");
```

or for a section in the page :

```
  $("#quote").load("HtmlPageUrl #container");
```